# Converting Keys of Pandas DF of Dictionaries to Columns and values as Data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a pandas DF with 5000 rows and 400+ columns containing identifiers as an index column with the remaining columns containing key value pairs in the form of a dictionary.

eg.

```
Identifier             0               1
identifier 1     {'key':'value'}     {'key2':'value2'}
```

I'm trying to get to a point where the data looks like this:

```
Identifier             key           key2
identifier1          value          value 2
```

I know we can use the following in order to create a df from a nested dictionary:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data).T
```

But that would require the data to look like this:

```
data = {'Identifier1': {'key': 'value', 'key2': 'value2'}}
```

When i use df.to_dict() on my current dataframe in order to get it to the above format, it looks like so:

```
{'Identifier1':{'0': {'key':'value'}, '1': {'key1':'value1'}...}}
```

Which I understand why. My question is two fold I suppose:

How can I get my data to a place where   df = pd.DataFrame(data).T works ?
Is there a better way to go about this?

EXAMPLE as requested:

Data looks like this:

| FileID | 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| file1 | {'key1':value1} | {'key3':value1} |
| file2 | {'key2':value1} | {'key1':value2} |

I'd like it to look like this:

| FileID | key 1 | key2 | key3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| file1 | value1 |  | value1 |
| file2 | value2 | value 1 |  |

EDIT 2: There are nonetypes within the dataframe I am working with as well. In trying out the solutions myself, I've come to realize that. Apologies for not including that information initially.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of `data`?

Comment: hi @richardec - i've provided what I'm working with and what I'm looking for. Let me know if that clears it up.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED**:

Here is my understanding of the question (as updated, including in the comments, by OP):

- Given a dataframe with:

  - leftmost column `FileID` and an arbitrary number of additional columns with each value in each row containing either None or a dict with 0 or more key/value pairs
- Produce a dataframe with:

  - the same leftmost column `FileID` and one additional column for each unique key in the union of all keys in the dicts contained in the original dataframe
  - in each row, the dict value for the key equal to the column label which was found in the original dataframe in the row with matching `FileID`

Here is code to do what is asked:

```py
df = pd.concat([df.FileID.to_frame(), df.apply(lambda x: {'FileID':x.FileID} | 
    {k:v for col in df.columns[1:] for k, v in (x[col] or {}).items()}, axis=1)], axis=1)
def foo(x):
    for y in x:
        if y is not np.nan:
            return y
    return np.nan
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.set_index('FileID').stack()).groupby('FileID').agg(foo).reset_index()
df2 = df2[['FileID'] + sorted(df2.columns[1:])]
```

Explanation:

- use `apply` to create one dict per row which is the union of the dicts in each column as well as a key/value pair for the row's `FileID`
- use `concat` to have the leftmost column be unchanged as `FileID`
- use `set_index` and `stack` to prepare the above dataframe to be used as a sequence of dicts to initialize a new dataframe using `from_records` such that it will have a column for each unique key in the union of all dicts in the original dataframe
- use `agg` with a custom function that for each `FileID` delivers the first non-NaN value for each key column, or NaN if that key is not found within the group for a given `FileID`
- use `reset_index` to restore `FileID` as a column
- (optional) sort the column labels

Full test code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'FileID':['file1','file2'], 0:[{'key1':'value1'}, {'key2':'value1'}], 1:[{'key3':'value1'}, None], 2:[{}, {'key1':'value2'}]})
print(df)

df = pd.concat([df.FileID.to_frame(), df.apply(lambda x: {'FileID':x.FileID} | 
    {k:v for col in df.columns[1:] for k, v in (x[col] or {}).items()}, axis=1)], axis=1)
def foo(x):
    for y in x:
        if y is not np.nan:
            return y
    return np.nan
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.set_index('FileID').stack()).groupby('FileID').agg(foo).reset_index()
df2 = df2[['FileID'] + sorted(df2.columns[1:])]
print(df2)
```

Input:

```
  FileID                   0                   1                   2
0  file1  {'key1': 'value1'}  {'key3': 'value1'}                  {}
1  file2  {'key2': 'value1'}                None  {'key1': 'value2'}
```

Output:

```
  FileID    key1    key2    key3
0  file1  value1     NaN  value1
1  file2  value2  value1     NaN
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I know I didn't include it in the question but any suggestion on handling data with none types/strings -_- I tried filling na with a dictionary to no avail

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand. Where would the none type/string data be in your example? Are they values within the dictionaries? What do you want to do with them?

Comment: These dicts exist inside of a dataframe. There are some nonetypes within the dataframe itself as well. 

additionally, walking through the code to try and troubleshoot, the second line in your last snippet looks like it may be incompatible with dicts given the pipe operand: 

unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'NoneType' and 'dict'

Comment: OK, please take a look at my updated answer which handles None values (as well as empty dicts).

Comment: Thanks! I tried it but I'm getting a KeyError of FileID (i checked my df and that field is there). Will keep trying to troubleshoot. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Can you provide an example of what's failing?

Comment: @redwytnblakII Do you need additional help? If not, please consider marking this (or one of the other answers) as "accepted".

Answer (score 0):

A combination of melting, popitem(), and pivoting back.

This first code block just creates a test table with plenty of different types of null values.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#example table
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'FileID': ['File_1','File_2','File_3','File_4'],
    'a': [{'key_5':9}, None, {}, {'key_9':13}], 
    'b': [np.nan, {'key_9':1}, {'key_11':2}, {'key_3':9}],
    'c': [{'key_6':4}, {'key_3':8}, '', {'key_11':10}],
})
print(df)
```

[image]

Here's the code to clean and reshape the data

```
#Melt to long form and extract the key/vals's with popitem
df = df.melt(id_vars='FileID').dropna()
df[['key','value']] = (
    df['value'].apply(lambda d: d.popitem() if d else (None,None)).to_list()
)

#will fail if the same key is used multiple times in the same row 
df = df.dropna().pivot(index='FileID',columns='key',values='value').reset_index()
df.columns.name = ''
print(df)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @mitoRibo - this kind of makes sense but it separates out the key value pairs when what I'm looking for is to maintain the keys as coloumns and values as data for each item in the index. Can you see if the example I provided in my question helps make more sense of what I'm trying to do?

Comment: @redwytnblakII thanks for the clarification, I think I've got it now

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a shot. Now just need to figure out how to handle none types -_-

Comment: @redwytnblakII it works with None/np.nan now